# Where in the law is the notion of a squatter defined?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-terms, any-jurisdiction

Is the notion of a squatter defined as a legal concept anywhere in the law? My understanding was always that it is legally defined as one who resides in a premise who had initially entered as a trespasser. Now the notion of a trespasser is a well established legal concept but where in the law of the idea of a squatter to be found with a definition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Squatter" is not a precisely defined legal term. It is [often used](https://www.canlii.org/en/#search/type=decision&text=EXACT(squatter)) to describe someone who is claiming to have a right to adverse possession. One legal dictionary defines "squatter" as "a person who has taken possession of a piece of land and occupied it by buildings or by cultivation and has by so taking possession of it asserted a right to it" ([Stroud's *Judicial Dictionary*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroud%27s_Judicial_Dictionary), "[squatter](https://archive.org/details/judicialdictiona00stro/page/1924/mode/2up)"), cited in *Spy Hill (Rural Municipality) v. Bradshaw* (1912), [7 DLR 941 (Sask K.B.) at para 7](https://canlii.ca/t/g725k#par7)).

See also *David Hoggan v The Esquimalt and Nanaimo Railway Company (Canada)* [[1894] UKPC 29 (3 May 1894)](https://www.bailii.org/uk/cases/UKPC/1894/1894_29.html):

> The term "squatter" is of course well known, and commonly used. It refers to a person who has taken possession of a piece of land and occupied it by buildings or by cultivation, and has by so taking possession of it asserted a right to it;
> and in the present case, where the possession has been exercised continuously for the period named in the section, the Act converts the possession into a right.